Lombok correcty installed on STS, still red underlined lines in IDE
I added a Lombok dependency in my pom.xml file:
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
 <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
 <version>1.18.22</version>
</dependency>

After Lombok library appeared in corresponding .m2 subfolder, I clicked on it, chose STS location and installed, without errors.
A new file named lombok was added to STS root folder and I was able to update/install my application using standard Maven commands.
Anyway, STS keeps on underlining setters/getters and constructors of classes where Lombok is used, as if it were not able to find those methods.
Following some posts even here on Stackoverflow, I removed the PROVIDED scope from dependency and modified my .ini file as in the following:
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.600.v20231106-1826.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.800.v20231003-1442
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.10.v20240120-1143/jre/bin
-vmargs
-javaagent:C:\Users\biagi\Downloads\sts-4.21.1.RELEASE\lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\biagi\Downloads\sts-4.21.1.RELEASE\lombok.jar
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off
-Dsun.java.command=SpringToolSuite4
-Dp2.trustedAuthorities=https://download.eclipse.org,https://archive.eclipse.org,https://cdn.spring.io
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--illegal-access=permit
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

Anyway, this didn't change a thing. Even if I can compile correctly, this problem could be bothersome in the future, since IDE may hide real errors among red lines.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

In STS when you go for the 'about page', it should say something like: `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2024-06 M1 (4.32.0 M1)
Build id: 20240411-1733
(c) Copyright lots more, elided
Lombok v1.18.33 "Edgy Guinea Pig" - 2024-05-14 is installed. https://projectlombok.org/` - is that 'lombok is installed' line in there?

Lombok needs to mess with the compiler in the IDE to work. Have you installed the necessary plugins for this?

Have you configured lombok as an annotation processor?
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

Also, the dependency should have scope=provided
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
<dependencies>

